# Immutability and General vs. Specific Types

Tags: java, interface, guava

This is in the context of creating an interface/API.

Best practices suggest using general rather than specific types in interfaces - e.g. `Map` rather than `HashMap`.

Best practices also suggest preferring immutable types over mutable ones.

So considering both of these suggestions (and leaving aside concerns about performance/memory-footprint, 3rd-party-libraries/dependencies and convenience/functionality) should a method in a public interface look like this

```
public List<SomeClass> someMethod(...)
```

or rather this

```
public ImmutableList<SomeClass> someMethod(...)
```

Comment: If the List returned is guaranteed to be immutable, it should look as 2), otherwise it should look as 1). What is an immutable List btw? If I cannot add to it, is it really a List?

Comment: The first one... Note that however an immutable _collection_ does not imply the immutability of its _elements_; it simply means that you cannot change the collection itself (replace/remove/add elements).

Comment: @JohnRasch Oh OK, thanks. I haven't really thought on or met that concept recently.

Comment: @JohnRasch aren't you mixing with something else? Guava's `Immutable*` collections are _really_ immutable

Comment: @JohnRasch What else (other than the list) would you then rather return in order to provide the caller with an ordered collection of return values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When this has been discussed among the Guava folks, the following has been said:

> The basic advice for types exchanged by APIs is this: choose the most general type that still conveys the relevant semantic information.
>
> I consider the trio of semantic guarantees made by ImmutableCollection to be extremely relevant for return values in almost any circumstance (those three being immutability, lack of null elements and guaranteed iteration order). So I would virtually always return ImmutableSet, not Set.
>
> We would really like people to view ImmutableSet etc. as being interfaces in every important sense of the word. There are only two reasons they are not: reliability of the immutability guarantee, and the fact that Java won't allow static methods on interfaces until JDK 8, and we wanted them there for convenience.
>
> Most people think ImmutableList is an implementation for this reason, but there are actually several to dozens of different implementations of some of these types; you just don't see them.

Answer (score 1):

If the method's contract guarantees that the List is immutable then the return type should be the ImmutableList rather than the List. This is much more explicit than simply mentioning that the List is immutable in the method's JavaDoc.

However, if the immutability of the list is an implementation detail, rather than a contract then the return type should be the List.

Answer (score 1):

Writing APIs is about having contract with the users.

Best practices are mostly for the context where you need to write APIs for third parties and need to define the interfaces.

We can have different view in different contexts. If you are writing library which is going to be used by third party, you need to consider that they should or should not change the object state.

If API is going to be consumed internally (with in same code base) & purpose is to achieve loose coupling then you need to think about ease of writing, extensibility and maintainability.

Immutable APIs would avoid the data inconsistency specially when you made lot of assumptions on state of the object. On the other hand, mutable object would allow to save development efforts.